# enlarge image (may be pixelate but not blurry)

Tags: python

I wrote a script that draws some images, usually not bigger than 50x50px. Then I want to display that image in a Tkinter window. But first I need to enlarge the image because 30x30px are too small for a user to see every single pixel generated by my script. So I wrote this:

```
multiplier = 4
image = np.full((height * multiplier, width * multiplier, 3), 0, dtype=np.uint8)

for r in range(height):
    for c in range(width):
        for i in range(multiplier):
            for j in range(multiplier):
                image[r * multiplier + i][c * multiplier + j] = original[r][c]
```

P.S. **original** was initialized the same way as **image**

Also I tried:

> resize((width * multiplier ,height * multiplier), Image.ANTIALIAS)

but it's not an option, because it makes an image look blurry. So what would be the better solution?

Example image:
[image]

Comment: `quality doesn't matter` and `but it's not an option, because it makes an image look blurry`... I think you need to update your question on what quality is good enough, since it actually does matter according to what you wrote.

Comment: Are the images like lines/geometric shapes? If so, maybe use `Pillow` and *"nearest neighbour"* resampling.

Comment: @Caramiriel I mean I need a sharp image, but I don't care if it looks pixelated

Comment: @MarkSetchell not geometric shapes, more of snake from the Snake game

Comment: TensorZoom is your friend.

Comment: Maybe add some sample images.

Comment: If you are using Pillow, then `Image.ANTIALIAS` will produce a "blurred" image, because that's specifically what that resampling filter is supposed to do. Have you tried using `Image.NEAREST` instead?

Comment: @MarkSetchell done!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest resizing with Nearest Neighbour resampling so you don't introduce any new, blurred colours - just ones already existing in your image:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("snake.png").convert('RGB')
im = im.resize((200,200),resample=Image.NEAREST)
im.save("result.png")
```

[image]

You can go from a Pillow image to a numpy array with:

```
numpy_array = np.array(pillowImage)
```

and from `numpy` array to a Pillow image with:

```
pillow_image = Image.fromarray(numpyArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use PIL.Image/openCV and PIL.ImageFilter modules:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
import cv2

image = cv2.resize(image, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
image = Image.fromarray(image)
```

Here, `fx` and `fy` are the values you have to set yourself. Hope this helps :)

Comment: If the image is too blurry. He said that his image was too blurry, so this is the step to sharpen it. It can always be removed.

Comment: Sharpen does not reverse blurring. It just enhances edges.

Comment: It doesn't offend me. I just don't think the sharpening step is useful for what the asker wants help with. If you disagree, you can just explain the purpose of that step. Some readers might think that "sharpen" does some kind of magical television "enhancement" that can make a blurry image unblurry.

Comment: If those users you refer to are not capable of googling what does sharpening step does, then I'm wrong, but I assume that they don't just copy the code without understanding and learning something from it.

Comment: one typo correction, an underscore is needed: interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use deep learning Image Super-Resolution (ISR) or (SR3) to enlarge images with good quality.

Here's the unofficial implementation of Image Super-Resolution via Iterative Refinement using Pytorch

https://github.com/Janspiry/Image-Super-Resolution-via-Iterative-Refinement

The paper: https://iterative-refinement.github.io/

Here's a video explanation by Two Minutes Paper https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCAF3PNEc_c

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using just PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
multiplier = 4
original = Image.open("snake.png")
width, height = original.size
resized = original.resize((width * multiplier, height * multiplier), resample=0)
resized.save("resized.png")
```

Using resample=0 is the key.